# Java UTF-8/UTF-16LE Input Conversion

Tags: java

I am trying to get my java console application to be able to take commands both from Windows PS and Linux Terminal while being run. It isn't working properly though because of a special character (like äüö etc) in a command.
When the program is being executed in Linux everything works fine because of UTF-8. My simple program just takes an input via a scanner and checks whether or not it matches a specific String. My expected command is read from a .txt file and is in UTF-8 format.

I tried to

```
Arrays.equals(userInputAsString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), expectedInputToExecuteCommandAsString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work while being run in PS.

I hope someone may be willing to help me!

Comment: Please try this `string = new String(string.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-16");`. Do let me know if it worked?

Comment: How does your program receive these strings?  As command-line arguments?  By reading standard input?  From a GUI?

Comment: Via stdin. There is no gui, just a console application